# Using CUDA printf outside the kernel to print device variables

Tags: c++, linux, cuda

What is the best way to print device variables in CUDA outside of the kernel?  Do I have to do a `cudaMemcpy` to the host and then print the resulting values?  When I try to use `printf` on pointers created using `cudaMalloc`, the program crashes.  It seems that most of the attention focuses on printing inside the kernel, not in regular code.

Thanks, Eric

Comment: This all depends on which version of the CUDA libraries you're using. I believe `printf` directly from kernel was added somewhere around 2.1. If you want to printf from hostside, you'll need to use `cudaMemcpy`, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "When I try to use printf on pointers created using cudaMalloc, the program crashes"

If you have this:

```
int *d_data, *h_data;
cudaMalloc(&d_data, DSIZE);
```

You cannot do this:

```
printf(" %d ", *d_data);
```

as this requires dereferencing a device pointer (`d_data`) in host code which is normally illegal in CUDA.

Instead you can do this:

```
h_data = (int *)malloc(DSIZE);
cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, DSIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
printf(" %d ", *h_data);
```

You can also investigate [Unified Memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd) which is new in CUDA 6, and see if it will serve your purposes.

And, as mentioned in the comments, devices of cc2.0 or greater support `printf` from the kernel, which operates on device data (only).

Answer (score 4):

An approach alternative to what suggested by Robert Crovella is to wrap the device pointer into a `thrust::device_ptr` by `thrust::device_pointer_cast`. This way is slightly more immediate when you need to access only very few elements of the device array. See the example below:

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

void main() {

    const int N = 10;

    int *h_data = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) h_data[i] = 3;

    int *d_data; cudaMalloc(&d_data, N*sizeof(int));    

    cudaMemcpy(d_data,h_data,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // --- Alternative approach
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr_key     = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_data);
    int i = 4; printf("Element number %d is equal to %d\n",i,(int)*(dev_ptr_key+i));

    getchar();

}
```